# return char** or passing array of char*

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I would like to get help in the following:

```
void Traceroute (char * hops[]){
   char* line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;
   int i = 0;
   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        hops[i] = line;
       i++;
   }
   printf ("value1: %s value2: %s\n",hops[0],hops[1]);
}
```

what I actually get is the latest value added to the array.!! hops
and I tried in main to define:

```
char* out[10]
```

and pass it but the same I'm always getting the same output.
Any suggestions ??
if you could help me please as well on how can I return char ** from a function ?

*** I don't want to use strings

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mixing C and C++ is never a good idea..

Comment: Looks like plain C code to me - why the C++ tag, I wonder ?

Comment: Your function's return type is void, so I don't understand how you want to return it.

Comment: You don't *want* to use strings or you *cannot* use strings? If it's the former, you need to lose that mentality.

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::string`, don't write C++. In addition to `std::string`, you should also be using `std::vector`, `std::list`, or `std::array` instead of raw arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getline` function can allocate memory for you, but **only** if you set `line` to NULL and `len` to 0 before each call. So the `Traceroute` function should look like this

```
int Traceroute( char *hops[], int size )
{
    char *line;
    size_t len;

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        line = NULL;
        len = 0;
        if ( getline( &line, &len, fp ) < 0 )
            break;

        hops[i] = line;
    }

    return i;
}
```

and should be called like this

```
int main( void )
{
    char *hops[10];

    int count = Traceroute( hops, 10 );
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        printf( "%s", hops[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from not allocating memory for `line`, you are doing what is called a shallow copy in this line:

```
hops[i] = line;
```

What it means is that you are copying the value of the pointer `line` to `hops[i]`, so at the end of the loop, all elements of `hops` are pointing to the same location in memory: wherever `line` is pointing.

What you need is a deep copy. Assuming you have allocated memory for `hops` before calling `Traceroute`, you can use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(hops[i], line);
```

since you don't want to use `std::string`.

Again, going back to start, you need to allocate enough memory for `line` to be able to hold a line of your file. Something like:

```
line = (char *) malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
```

and then, at the very end of your function:

```
free(line);
```

EDIT: Adding memory allocation for `hops`:

I'm assuming you want to do this outside `Traceroute`. So, before calling that function, use:

```
int i = 0;
const int nlines = 10;
char *hops[nlines];
for(i = 0; i < nlines; ++i)
    hops[i] = (char *) malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
```

And then, when you are done with the array `hops`, you need to free the memory:

```
for(i = 0; i < nlines; ++i)
    free(hops[i]);
```

Comment: If you extended your answer with the description of the memory allocation for hops array, i'd upvote it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GézaTörök, I'm not very up on my C knowledge, hopefully I didn't make any mistakes though :-)

Comment: Seems fair enough :) +1

Answer (score 0):

`char* out[10]` allocates space for 10 character *pointers* only.  You read every line into the same location (`line`), and assign that pointer to each element of the array, so they are all the same.  But you never actually set aside space for this line, much less space for each line independently, which means you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You want to dynamically allocate and copy each char sequence:

Thus:

```
hops[i] = line;
```

Becomes:

```
size_t nSize = sizeof(char) * read; //Get the byte size of the data
hops[i] = malloc(nSize); //Allocate the proper number of chars
memcpy(hops[i], line, nSize); //Copy the data to that hops entry
```

This is because the data at line gets overwritten each iteration of the loop and since hops[i] points to that same area the data at hops[i] gets overwritten.